# Safari don't load images in specific page

Tags: image, debugging, safari

I'm launching a site and from safari this page doesn't load any image: http://kine.kevinmamaqi.com/estetica/. I can't find why and after from two different macos, clearing cache and looking for a bug I can't find a solution.

Any idea why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the use of accents in some image filenames (estética instead of estetica). From firefox and chrome it was working fine, but it didn't from safari, I don't know why.

Changing the filenames solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Use these steps to remove cookies, cache, and other data stored by Safari for a specific site:**

1. Choose Safari > Preferences.
2. Click the Privacy icon.
3. Click the Details button.
4. Search for the name or domain of the website whose data you want to
   remove.
5. In the results list, click the domain (like example.com)
   that has data you want to remove. Click Remove.

When you're finished, click Done and close the preferences window.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't have anything to do with cache.